# Why does Function.prototype.bind return a constructor?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the polyfill of `Function.prototype.bind` method.

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Can anyone `explain` me why do we do this? If i am not invoking my `fn` with `new` operator, i see this steps as un-necessary. Why does the returned `fn` need to be a `constructor` if not invoked via new operator?.

```
fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
fBound.prototype = new fNOP();    
return fBound;
```

Can we do something like this below instead of creating a `new constructor`?

```
fBound.prototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
return fBound
```

Comment: _[This comment is off topic]_ If `Function.prototype.bind` needs to be polyfilled, so does `Object.create`, because both are from ES5. So you can't polyfill `Function.prototype.bind` with `Object.create`. Besides, `Object.create` is actually much more difficult to polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

You could... if `Object.create` was supported.

But if you are polyfilling `Function.prototype.bind`, it's likely you must polyfill `Object.create` too.

And the polyfill of `Object.create` is basically the part you find unnecessary:

```js
Object.create = (function() {
    var fNOP = function() {};
    return function (prototype) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) throw Error('Second argument not supported');
        if (typeof prototype != 'object') throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');
        fNOP.prototype = prototype;
        var result = new fNOP();
        fNOP.prototype = null;
        return result;
    };
})();
```

Comment: Actually `Object.create` seems impossible to polyfill, if take account of edge cases, for example `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: @Leo True, but it can be polyfilled in some cases. And for those, the polifyll does what OP thinks is unnecessary.

Comment: Yep, I referred to edge cases.